# jasper ireport field length problem

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

If my report contains too many fields and it is already in landscape mode, few fields like email address or url fields may be too large while displaying url/email data on the report how do we make sure data is not truncated over the report ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the 'strech with overflow' checbox on the text-field (if youre editting the xml directly, this would be `<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true"`)

This would cause fields that are too big to overflow to the next line, instead on being truncated.