# generating pdf using jrxml

Tags: jasper-reports, pdf-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jasper ireport field length problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985286/jasper-ireport-field-length-problem)

I'm working on this web application done using spring. 
it generates pdf files using .jrxml files.

the problem i'm facing is when the width of the textual data is too long all the alignments in pdf goes wrong and it displays a wired looking pdf statement.

i'm new to jrxml stuff and jasper reports.

is there any way we can modify the jrxml file to dynamically change the width of tables printed in pdf, or print the text in multiple lines to solve this issue?

currently it has a fixed width

```
            <line>
            <reportElement x="395" y="28" width="79" height="1"/>
        </line>
```

hope this information is enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139366/display-full-text-in-excel-without-truncation & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985286/jasper-ireport-field-length-problem & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814123/automatically-stretch-or-shrink-textfield-depending-on-text-lenght & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300383/dynamic-column-cell-width

Comment: thanx for providing this links, they were helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the textfield property "Stretch With Overflow" to true, this may help you.